# Edit unbound Record In Access Database

Tags: database, vb.net

I finally have it working it appears I forgot some tick marks. The code below seems to work.

If anyone sees anything drastically wrong with it I hope they will let me know.

```
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & PathCMDB() & "';"

    sql = "Update [Machine Attributes] set [VALUE] =  " & e.Value & " Where " & _
            "([Machine Attributes].[Machine ID] =" & m_machineID & _
            " ) And ([Machine Attributes].[Attribute Type ID] = " & e.Row.Tag & " ) ;"

    connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)

    Try
        connection.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

        Dim check As Integer = cmd.ExecuteReader.RecordsAffected
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        connection.Open()

        If check < 1 Then 'We need to add the record that does not exist

            sql = "INSERT INTO [Machine Attributes]([Attribute Type ID],[Machine ID],[Value]) VALUES('" & _
                    e.Row.Tag & "','" & m_machineID & "','" & e.Value & "')"

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)


        End If

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")

    End Try
```

Comment: where is the code to edit the info?  or save it?

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Just initiate a nonquery which executes an update command

Here's a bit of pseudocode. just tinker with the SQL string variable.

```
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    dim sql as string = "Update [Machine Attributes] set [field to edit] =  " & controlwhithdata.property & " Where " & _
        "[Key field] = " & controlwithkeyfield.property & ";"
    Dim oledbcmD As OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    Dim connetionString As String



    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & PathCMDB() & "';"
    Try

    connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    connection.Open()


        oledbcmD.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
         connection.close()
         msgbox(ex.tostring)
    End Try
```

**Side Note** Instead of using an adapter, you may want to look into using Readers to fetch data from database to control.

Comment: Don't I need this code in thee somewhere so it updates the proper record? "([Machine Attributes].[Machine ID] = " & m_machineID & _
        ") And ([Machine Attributes].ID = " & n_AttID & " )"

Comment: You were right I just needed to play with the sql and it is working just fine. Thanks you for the insight

Comment: OK Now that I have the following code working I have discovered that it does not add a record if it does not exist. SO I guess my question is, can I change the following code to do both insert and update or do I need to check first the update?

Comment: Forgot to put up the code        sql = "Update [Machine Attributes] set [VALUE] =  " & e.Value & " Where "([Machine Attributes].[Machine ID] =" &  machineID & " ) And ([Machine Attributes].[Attribute Type ID] = " & e.Row.Tag & " ) ;"
        connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try

Comment: I tried this <code>    connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
Try
connection.Open()
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
Dim check As Integer = cmd.ExecuteReader.RecordsAffected
If check < 1 Then 'We need to add the record that does not exist
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
sql = "INSERT INTO [Machine Attributes] ('Attribute Type ID','Machine ID','Value') VALUES('" & e.Row.Tag & "','" & m_machineID & "','" & e.Value & "')"
End If
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception  MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
End Try</code>

Comment: You have put a wall of text in these comments. This is not the way to do it. If you can, please just [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20301647/edit) your question so that others which will see it in the future can understand what you did.

Comment: I have updated the code. Sorry for the wall